# Mysql database Alias Filter

Tags: mysql, filter, alias

```
SELECT *
     , t.BG as TY
     , IF (t.BG >= 15, 'Y', 'D') AS Toplam 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT Uzmanadid AS Uzman_Ad
            , Kurumid
            , SUM(Bireysel)
            , IF(Kurumid like '%L%',
                IF(SUM(Bireysel) > 20, 200, 10)
              , IF(SUM(Bireysel) > 90, 20, 15)
                ) AS BG
        FROM Tbl_pss2 
       GROUP 
          BY Uzman_Ad) as t
```

I want to filter it, where Toplam = 'Y' but I cannot do it. I tried this one:

```
SELECT *,t.BG as TY, IF (t.BG >= 15, 'Y', 'D') AS Toplam FROM (SELECT
Uzmanadid AS Uzman_Ad, Kurumid, SUM(Bireysel), IF(Kurumid like '%L%',
IF(SUM(Bireysel) > 20, 200, 10), IF(SUM(Bireysel) > 90, 20, 15)) AS BG
FROM Tbl_pss2 WHERE Toplam = 'Y' GROUP BY Uzman_Ad) as t
```

But it didnt work. If I try to filter it with already existing column name (exp. Where Uzmanid = 'Alex') it works. But the other code doesnt work, because it is just alias not already exist.

So how can I filter this

Comment: Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of the column `Toplam` is:

```
IF (t.BG >= 15, 'Y', 'D')
```

so the condition:

```
Toplam = 'Y'
```

is `TRUE` when:

```
t.BG >= 15
```

So you can filter like this:

```
WHERE t.BG >= 15
```